# In the borframework, application works locally, but does not work post results on the channel

Tags: azure, botframework

I have written code for the bot that is uploaded on the azure website.

When i test the app locally, every result gets posted. However, after uploading it to the server, the results are being generated but nothing is being posted on the channels

Comment: Do you have an example of channel you use ? I guess you're using node js ?

Comment: What do you mean the results are being generated? Do you send back any replies? Are they well-formatted (From, Recipient fields, etc.)? Are there any errors (exception, error message on the channel)?

Comment: @Thegaram. I developed the application for the bot using node js. When i test it on the emulator, it works fine with the result posting. When i deployed the application on the azure webapp, the app started working. All of a sudden it stops responding throwing a 500 internal server error, with no trace of what error occured.

Comment: @HiteshSuvarna: did you use HTTPS endpoint?

Comment: Still need additional information to understand the problem.  Where are testing the deployed application?  With the emulator using ngrok?  On one of the channels (i.e. Skype)?   What's the format of the message you are sending that results in a 500?